# Dropped my ring in a shower drainage. How do I get it back?

Tags: drain

Unlike sink in a washing bin, I don't have access to the U shape part of the pipe and it's not visible. What is the recommended way to get the ring? The ring is quite heavy and not magnetic; I'm have doubts that wet vacuum can do it.

[image: The sink.]

Comment: If it's been a while since you cleaned the P-trap, you might be able to hook the ring out, along with a wad of hair using a cut coat hanger with a nice little bendy hook on the long end. A drain zip it is also a possiblity: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drain+zip+it&t=ffsb&ia=products

Answer (score 2):

“Curse us and crush us, my precious is lost!”

Perhaps a -

[Endoscope - Inspection Camera - Endoscope camera- Snake Camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y6D4KXC)

for your phone and a wire bent into a hook ?

Comment: If it's in the trap, you're in luck.  But carefully go looking for it  (the endoscope is a good tool, and they're relatively inexpensive), rather than blindly pushing around a hook hoping to snag it; that's likely to dislodge it and then it will be gone.  In fact, some of these endoscopes come with various attachments, like a hook, so you can see what you're doing to grab it.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s in the P-trap, you can suck it out with a wet-vac.

Answer (score 0):

Try watching in with a tooth mirror and a flashlight, if you can see it that way, use a hook shaped piece of iron yarn and hook it. Otherwise I think hiring a plumber is the best option (if the ring is valuable)